# Fragment view going over actionbar on keyboard open

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, scrollview

I've been trying to solve it for a few days and have been looking for an answer for this.
Does anybody know why this happens?

**Closed keyboard** vs **open keyboard**:

[image: Closed Keyboard] [image: Openend Keyboard]

My MainActivity.xml (where the root for fragment transaction)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have another `Fragment` with a `ScrollView` and without any type of input, so I don't use the keyboard there and it works fine. Please help me.

Comment: What do you have in the manifest file for the particular activity?

Comment: <activity
            android:name="main.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>     I've tried every InputMode there is and still didnt work

Comment: Try changing "adjustPan" to "resize"

Comment: My bad. Can you confirm you have android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: Yes, its still going over the action bar

Comment: @TalHindi Post your `AndroidManifest`, please.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/w7eP3/